# Web application is very slow when run from the server it exists

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, windows-server-2003

We have two servers in the same network. One of them is the server where a web application and the database it connects to resides. When I run the application from its own server applciation is very slow. But if I run it from the other server its relatively fast. I've been told to check Firewall but the related service is not even running so firewall is off.
Both of the servers are Win Server 2003. The application is written in ASP.NET and the databse is Oracle 10g. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same happens when using ASP.Net Development Server, from what I can tell, the server has been designed to assign its resources to page requests from foreign clients, this is due to the fact that web servers are made to server many foreign web requests.

Another thing, if the Oracle server is not local this will happen.

Comment: The Oracle is in the same server.

Comment: Then it must be the fact that foreign requests take preference over local ones